# "bindParam" with multi-parameters after "Limit" couldn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have encounterd this problem and can't find a solution.

```
public function getComments($postId,$pageCmt){
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    $cmtNb=3;
    $r=($pageCmt-1)*3;
    
    $req = $db->prepare('SELECT id, comments FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY ind_date DESC,date_comments DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?' );
    
    $req->bindParam(1,$postId,\PDO::PARAM_INT);         
    $req->bindParam(2,$cmtNb,\PDO::PARAM_INT );                 
    $req->bindParam(3,$r,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
    
    $req->execute(array($postId,$cmtNb,$r));
    
    return $req;
}
```

It seems the problems comme from the parameter after LIMIT,
coz if I take off `LIMIT ? OFFSET ?` the codes can work with the first parameter `$postId`, comments will be fetched.

But if I add the codes with `LIMIT ? OFFSET?` on the page there will be no comments fetched but no error showed neither.

Any idea?

Comment: My suggestion is remove the argument from the `execute`, since the preceding `bindParam` calls have already done the placeholder binding. (We are going to assume the PHP error reporting is enabled, and PDO connection is configured to throw an exception when an error occurs ie. `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` My personal preference would be to use `bindValue` in place of `bindParam` for values that are known at bind time, also my personal preference would be to use `LIMIT ? , ?` form rather than `OFFSET`

Comment: Frist thanks to your suggestion, well, the PDO connection seems to be ok, because if i remove the 2e and 3e "?",this codes can work, but if i add the 2e and 3e variables, even use bindValue, it can not work.....!.

Comment: For debubbing, what happens when we leave off `OFFSET ?`, just the `LIMIT` ? What if we hardcode the LIMIT clause, without any bind placeholders (as a test) e.g. `LIMIT 3`, or `LIMIT 0,3` ? If that works, then what is the value of `$r` (we could vardump it for debugging.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of the `array($postId,$cmtNb,$r)` in the `execute`.

Comment: @spencer7593 Hello, i tried again today with your methods but still using "LIMIT ?OFFSET ?" it works!  thanks and "vardump" can really be very useful. BTW when i use "LIMIT ?,?" it will Not work,still don't know why.

Comment: know that with the MySQL standard "LIMIT ?, ?" form, the first value is the offset, the second is the maximum number of rows to return.  Those values are in reverse order from the "LIMIT ? OFFSET ?" form (which MySQL added to be compatible with PostgreSQL.)  Are we sure we're doing `LIMIT 0,3` (skip zero rows), and not `LIMIT 3,0`  (skip three rows then return at most  zero rows)? ... i have no other explanation why  "LIMIT 3 OFFSET 6" would give a different result than 
"LIMIT 6,3"  ... the question is tagged mysql so I've assumed we're talking about MySQL and not some other RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Solution today:

By using still " LIMIT ? OFFSET ?" and then:

```
      $req->bindValue(1,$postId,\PDO::PARAM_INT);          
      $req->bindValue(2,$cmtNb,\PDO::PARAM_INT );               
      $req->bindValue(3,$r,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
      var_dump($r);

      $req->execute();
```

It works perfectly today!, thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could try to concatenate the values into the query directly because the value cannot be spoofed by a user, the values are set on the server side.

Also, you do not need to use `bindParam()` AND pass the values to `execute()`.

Your code can be revised as

```
$req = $db->prepare('SELECT id, comments FROM comments WHERE post_id = ? ORDER BY ind_date DESC,date_comments DESC LIMIT {$cmtNb} OFFSET {$r}' );
$req->execute(array($postId));
```

If you ever need to use a value specified by a user for `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`, you need to verify on the server side if that value should be accepted before running the query.

Comment: The MySQL Reference Manual disagrees with the first sentence in this answer. MySQL does allow ? placeholders in the LIMIT clause, at least since version 5.6. (If single quotes are being introduced into the SQL text, I think that depends on the datatype in the bind; PDO doesn't do that with other databases, maybe it depends on whether server side prepares are being used ?)  My personal preference would be to use `bindValue` in place of `bindParam` (given that the bind values are known at bind time)

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks. I removed the first sentence. From personal experience, this method works for me. As for actually passing the values, my preference is passing the values to `execute()` because it looks cleaner to me. Though, I use a class wrapper I made so I don't have to do it at all.

Comment: Passing values to the bind placeholders in the execute works when we want to bind all the values as strings PDO::PARAM_STR.

Comment: Thanks for you guys, but I tried the method with { $variable} but still not working......is anything wrong with the datatype: as i bind with int and in the 2e and 3e parameters are int to me, so i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @spencer7593 Doesn't MySQL handle the types pretty well regardless of the way it's binded? I _always_ pass the values using the `execute()` method and I've never had a single problem with it.

Comment: Other databases (like Oracle and Teradata) aren't nearly as generously loose with datatypes. And my personal preference is to make the datatypes explicit. For trivial examples, it doesn't matter. But I find it to be helpful when I'm working on code that I haven't written, where I'd rather see each of the binds enumerated, each on a separate line, especially helpful when there's more than a dozen. I also tend to prefer named placeholders to the positional, but that just comes down to preferences in coding style. (I'm not going to dissuade anyone from doing the bindValue on separate lines.)

Comment: @spencer7593 You are making me want to update my PDO wrapper to include a way to specify datatypes lol